# How test if an NA value is equal to zero; replace if so, leave as NA if not

Tags: r, replace, na

### Edited as hadn't included the full set of factors in the example dataset, which is causing the original solutions to break.

I'm trying to clean a dataset by determining if an NA should be replaced with a 0, or if left as NA.

The below is a sample data set. 'Dom.Supply' should equal the sum of the remaining factors.  For example, the NAs that appear in rows 3:5 for 'Feed', 'Waste', 'Processing' and 'Other.Uses' could each be replaced with 0 as the sum of factors with values (ie. 'Food' and 'Seed') is equal to the value of 'Dom.Supply.  However, in rows 1 & 2, the NAs would have to remain as the sum of 'Food' and 'Seed' is not equal to 'Dom.Supply'.

```
Region  Country Group   Item    Year    Production  Imports Stock.Var   Exports Dom.Supply  Feed    Seed    Waste   Processing  Other.Uses  Food
NAm.Oceania Australia   Cereals Rye 1961    11  0   0   2   9   NA  1   NA  NA  NA  7
NAm.Oceania Australia   Cereals Rye 1962    10  0   0   3   7   NA  1   NA  NA  NA  5
NAm.Oceania Australia   Cereals Rye 1963    10  0   0   1   9   NA  2   NA  NA  NA  7
NAm.Oceania Australia   Cereals Rye 1964    14  0   -5  0   9   NA  2   NA  NA  NA  7
NAm.Oceania Australia   Cereals Rye 1965    11  0   5   0   16  NA  2   NA  NA  NA  14
```

I had though to use the `replace` function as follows (as an example, but not the operation I wish to use), but this is a simplistic replacement of NAs with 0s rather than a test that NA=0.

```
data$AF2 <- 1-((replace(data$Feed, is.na(data$Feed), 0) + (replace(data$Seed,
    is.na(data$Seed), 0)) / data$Dom.Supply))
```

Thanks!

Comment: So you want to replace the NAs with 0s only in the rows where the shown numbers add to Dom.Supply?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use this:

```
DF <- read.table(text = "Dom.Supply  Feed    Seed    Waste   Processing  Other.Uses  Food
9   NA  1   NA  NA  NA  7
7   NA  1   NA  NA  NA  5
9   NA  2   NA  NA  NA  7
9   NA  2   NA  NA  NA  7
16  NA  2   NA  NA  NA  14", header = TRUE)

ix <- rowSums(DF[, -1], na.rm = TRUE) == DF[, 1]
DF[ix,] <- lapply(DF[ix,], function(x) {
  x[is.na(x)] <- 0
  x
})
#  Dom.Supply Feed Seed Waste Processing Other.Uses Food
#1          9   NA    1    NA         NA         NA    7
#2          7   NA    1    NA         NA         NA    5
#3          9    0    2     0          0          0    7
#4          9    0    2     0          0          0    7
#5         16    0    2     0          0          0   14
```

Comment: you can also avoid using `lapply` and do `DF[ix, ][is.na(DF[ix, ])] <- 0`

Comment: Thanks, @CathG. That seems to be simpler code, but I struggle to understand the syntax as compared to Roland's (I'm still in nappies, obviously).

Comment: @Expat_Canuck, it's just saying to replace the NAs by 0 wherever there is any among the `ix` rows ;-)

Answer (score 3):

CathG answer deserves to be in a real answer, not only as a comment (posting here as community wiki):

```
DF <- read.table(text = "Dom.Supply  Feed    Seed    Waste   Processing  Other.Uses  Food
9   NA  1   NA  NA  NA  7
7   NA  1   NA  NA  NA  5
9   NA  2   NA  NA  NA  7
9   NA  2   NA  NA  NA  7
16  NA  2   NA  NA  NA  14", header = TRUE)

ix <- rowSums(DF[, -1], na.rm = TRUE) == DF[, 1]
DF[ix, ][is.na(DF[ix, ])] <- 0 
DF
#  Dom.Supply Feed Seed Waste Processing Other.Uses Food
#1          9   NA    1    NA         NA         NA    7
#2          7   NA    1    NA         NA         NA    5
#3          9    0    2     0          0          0    7
#4          9    0    2     0          0          0    7
#5         16    0    2     0          0          0   14
```

**EDIT**
In case you have `NAs` in the column `Dom.Supply`, `ix` will have a `NA` for the corresponding row. You can change the `NA` into `FALSE` (as you want to leave the `NAs` in the other columns as `NAs`):

```
ix <- rowSums(DF[, -1], na.rm = TRUE) == DF[, 1]
ix[is.na(ix)] <- FALSE
DF[ix, ][is.na(DF[ix, ])] <- 0
```

*Example, with the same original `DF`:*

```
DF[2, 1] <- NA
ix <- rowSums(DF[, -1], na.rm = TRUE) == DF[, 1]
ix[is.na(ix)] <- FALSE
DF[ix, ][is.na(DF[ix, ])] <- 0 
DF
#  Dom.Supply Feed Seed Waste Processing Other.Uses Food
#1          9   NA    1    NA         NA         NA    7
#2         NA   NA    1    NA         NA         NA    5
#3          9    0    2     0          0          0    7
#4          9    0    2     0          0          0    7
#5         16    0    2     0          0          0   14
```

Comment: @CathG, what syntax is needed to avoid your second line of code breaking if there is an NA in any of the column 1? Substituting the '7' in column 1 row 2 with an NA generates the following error: Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, ix, , value = list(Dom.Supply = c(0,  : 
  missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames".  Thanks.

Comment: @Expat_Canuck, the problem is that it results in a `NA` in `ix`. I suppose that in this case, you want to leave everything to NA? I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @Expat_Canuck, sorry for the late reply, I didn't get a notification for your comment :-(